# Minimal Linux with kernel and BusyBox: /etc/inittab is ignored, only /init is executed

Tags: linux, init-script, init, busybox, sysvinit

I managed to create a small and fully functional live Linux CD which contains only kernel (compiled with default options) and BusyBox (compiled with default options + static, all applets present, including `/sbin/init`). I had no issues to create `initrd` and populate `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys` and also I had no issues at all with my `/init` shell script.

Recently I read that BusyBox supports `/etc/inittab` configurations (at least to some level) and I very much would like to do either of the following:

- Forget about my `/init` shell script and rely entirely on `/etc/inittab` configuration.
- Use both `/init` shell script and `/etc/inittab` configuration.

Now the actual problem - it seems that `/etc/inittab` is completely ignored when my distro boots up. The symptoms are:

- When I remove `/init` and leave only `/etc/inittab` I end up with kernel panic. My assumption is that kernel doesn't execute `/sbin/init` at all, or that `/sbin/init` doesn't find (or read) `/etc/inittab`.
- I read that BusyBox should work fine even without `/etc/inittab`. So, I removed both `/init` and `/etc/inittab` and guess what - kernel panic again.
- I tried to execute `/sbin/init` from my shell and after several guesses which included `exec /sbin/init`, `setsid /sbin/init` and `exec setsid /sbin/init` I ended up with kernel panic. Both with and without /etc/inittab being present on the file system.

Here is the content of my `/init` shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dmesg -n 1
mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
setsid cttyhack /bin/sh
```

At this point I don't care what the content of the `/etc/inittab` would be, as long as I have a way to know that the configuration there actually works. I tried several `/etc/inittab` configurations, all based on the information which I found [here](https://svn.mcs.anl.gov/repos/ZeptoOS/trunk/BGL/ionode-ramdisk/build-tools/busybox/busybox-0.60.5/scripts/inittab).

As a bare minimum my /etc/inittab contained just this one line:

```
::sysinit:/bin/sh
```

Again - I ended up with kernel panic and it seems that `/etc/inittab` was ignored.

Any suggestions how to force my little live distro to work fine with BusyBox's `/etc/inittab` are highly appreciated!

**Update:**

- Just to make it clear - I **do not** have kernel panic troubles with my current `/init` shell script both with and without `/etc/inittab`. It all works fine, my `/bin/ash` console works great and I don't experience any unexpected troubles. The only issue is that `/etc/inittab` is completely ignored, as I described above.
- I examined 3 different live Linux distributions: Slax, Finnix and SysResCD. All of them have `/init` and none of them have `/etc/inittab`. In addition [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd#Implementation) concludes my suspicion that `/sbin/init` is not invoked at all.

Comment: If you came here, take a look at [Minimal Linux Live](https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal) which seems to do what the wants, and just works: https://github.com/ivandavidov/minimal

Comment: Ah, the OP wrote Minimal Linux Live! Man you rock.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, I did a lot of extensive research and I found out what was wrong. Let's start one by one:

- When we use `initramfs` boot scheme the first process which the kernel invokes is the `/init` script. The kernel will never try to execute `/sbin/init` directly.
- `/init` is assigned process identifier 1. This is very important!
- The problem now is that `/sbin/init` can only be started as `PID 1` but we are already running `/init` as PID 1.
- The solution is to execute the command line `exec /sbin/init` while we are still inside `/init`. In this way the new process (which is `/sbin/init`) will inherit the PID from its parent (`/init` with PID 1) and that's all we have to do.

The problem I experienced with my initial configuration (see the question) was due to the fact that the last thing my `/init` script does is to spawn new `/bin/sh` process which is assigned brand new PID. From this point it's impossible to run `/sbin/init` directly from interactive console because even when we execute the command line `exec /sbin/init`, the best we achieve is to assign the same PID which has already been assigned to the shell and this PID is definitely not PID 1.

Long story short - execute the command line `exec /sbin/init` directly from `/init` and that's all.